# Excel - Extracting lists for countifs using Slicers and Pivottables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I'm developing a report at the moment and while most of the report uses pivot tables to visualise the data some of the work that I'm doing is too complex to use pivot tables.

With the inclusion of slicers it has been requested of me to find a way to incorporate the selections in the slicers in to the formula of the manual section.

I've managed to get as far as creating dummy tables which have the subheadings for the slicers in them i.e. for the slicer Country I have a table with just country in the rows which displays the chosen options in the slicer for country and updates with any of the other slicers.

By using:
    {=SUM(COUNTIFS(data[country],A1:A5))}
Where A1:A5 is the area in the pivot table with the countries listed. I am able to correctly count the number of rows where the country matches.
But when I included a second list such as
    {=SUM(COUNTIFS(data[country],A1:A5,data[industry],C1:C5))}
the results don't match.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "the results don't match". What exactly do you need the second formula to count? A link to an image would help.

Comment: Hey @jeffreyweir what is happening is it's only selecting the first results from a1:a5 and c1:c5. The second formula is counting rows in a dataset that match criteria from those lists.